# Find value of command line argument in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am passing a list of arguments while running a batch file and need the value of a particular argument -logdir to set some dir path in my batch file. How can I first check if the `-logdir` is passed as argument and if it is passed get its value and set it in a variable.

I am running it like:

```
test.bat -env test1 -logdir C:\Users\...\log -userhome ... -log ...
```

and many more arguments. These arguments can be passed in different order.

I am able to fetch the list of arguments passed using below.

```
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /A argCount+=1
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%
set /a count=0
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %argCount%) do (
  set /a count=!count!+1
  call set "var=%%!count!"
  echo var= %!var!
)
```

But I am facing issues comparing this args with the value. I tried using if as below :

```
if -> if "!_var!" equ "-logdir" set /a logdir="%%!count!"
```

But getting error as syntax not correct.

Comment: what arguments are you passing? is there an example? Are they in pairs? Are the arguments always passed in the same order?

Comment: That question is unanswerable without knowing what operating system and which programming/scripting language you are using. Also, you should show what you already tried.

Comment: I am running it like :  test.bat -env test1 -logdir C:\Users\..\log -userhome .. -log and many more. These arguments can be passed in different order.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 OS .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Given that the arguments received by your batch file are allocated to `%1`, `%2`, `%3`, `%4` etc. what's stopping you from using an `if` statement? e.g. `If /I "%~1"=="-LogDir" Set "var=%~2"` etc.

Comment: Please add all relevant information into your question by [edit]ing it rather than spreading it over multiple comments!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :parseArgs %*
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1

echo env       %env%
echo log       %log%
echo logdir    %logdir%
echo userhome  %userhome%
exit /b

:parseArgs
for %%A in (%*) do (
    if defined arg (
        call set "%%arg%%=%%~1"
        set "arg="
    ) else (
        for %%B in (
          env
          log
          logdir
          userhome
        ) do if "%%~A" == "-%%~B" set "arg=%%~B"

        if not defined arg (
            >&2 echo %%A is an invalid argument.
            exit /b 1
        )
    )
    shift
)
exit /b
```

After the `for %%B in (` line is where the valid keywords
are located. If an argument does not define `arg`, then it
exits the `:parseArgs` label in which you can check
`errorlevel` to exit the script.

Does any order with arguments.

E.g.

```
myscript -env current -log text.log
```

which would have variable `%env%` with value `current` etc.

If you want default values in case i.e. `-log` is not passed, then
just e.g. `set "log=%~n0.log"` before the `call :parseArgs` line.

Answer (score 0):

You claim there can be "many more arguments". The `%x` syntax can only use the first nine parameters, so with the available `%1` to `%9` you can only process four pairs, which might be too few. Gladly, the parameters 10... are not lost (although not directly accessible). You can shift the parameter list to the left.

As the parameter pairs "can be passed in different order", it's best to just assign the even parameters (values) to variables named like the odd parameters (variables). I addes some REM's to the code to explain it:

```
@echo off & setlocal
:loop
if "%~2" == "" goto :done  & REM if no other pair of parameters then done
set "%~1=%~2" & REM set variable
shift & REM remove first...
shift & REM ... two params
goto :loop  & REM and repeat
:done
REM show parameters:
set -
```

Note: no syntax check. Parameters are expected to be repeatedly `-param` and `value`

To pass parameters with spaces (or other delimiters), quote them like

```
test.bat -env test1 -logdir "C:\path with spaces\log"
```