# read batch parameters with single and double -

Tags: batch-file

my batch file is ProcessMe.bat

the Command is this

```
ProcessMe   -color  blue    -type  high    --size  large    --tag  gift
```

the parameters order is not fixed

```
ProcessMe     -type  high  --tag  gift  --size  large  -color  blue    

ProcessMe     --tag  gift   -color  blue   --size  large   -type  high

ProcessMe     --size  large    -type  high  -color  blue   --tag  gift
```

and parameters are coming in the same format single - and double --

I want to read these parameters in my .bat file

I tried these but non worked

```
echo %--size%

echo %-size%

echo %size%

echo --size

echo -size

echo size

echo %--size

echo %-size

echo %size
```

how can I get parameters values in .bat file?!

Comment: @michael_heath this is just use parms order, in my case order is exchangable.

Comment: Perhaps an answer at [Find value of command line argument in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55596264/9012170). That does any order.

Comment: I think you are mistaking batch arguments for powershell arguments. In batch-files, arguments are passed through number variables recognized by a single `%` like `%1` where `%1` is the first argument, `%2` the second and so on where `%0` is teh path of the batch file.

Comment: There is no `params` function in powershell. That is a powershell command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each switch having only one value, This one is very easy.
Use shift and assign the value to the switch name until all Params have been processed with the aid of a loop

```bat
@Echo off
Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Call :PROCESS %*
For %%A in (Type tag size color) DO Set %%A
Pause
Exit /B
:PROCESS
    IF "%~1" == "" Exit /B 0
    Set "PARAM=%~1"
    Set "PARAM=!PARAM:-=!"
    SHIFT
    Set "!Param!=%~1"
    SHIFT
Goto :PROCESS
```